# Converting to a non-daylight savings timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

In python, I am trying to convert a bunch of UTC datetimes into a localized timezone but STANDARD time year round. For example, for pacific time, I need PST year round, not PDT and PST switching from summer to winter.  Or to rephrase my question, is there a way to specify 'Standard' time for a timezone?

Comment: Note that in most cases, this is a mistake.  The people in the Pacific time zone do not actually have a choice unto themselves whether they use PST or PDT.  That is part of the definition of being in the Pacific time zone.  Perhaps this was handed to you as a requirement? If so, the right thing to do is to learn about time zones and then provide those learnings to whomever handed you the requirement.  Implementing it as asked is deliberately implementing a bug.  (I'm presuming a lot here, apologies if that is not the case, just you are not the first to ask and it usually the response.)

Comment: The exception would be if by PST you are referring to [Pitcairn Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/pitcairn), used in Pitcairn Islands only, which is UTC-8 year round.  But I don't think that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the UTC offset for a specific time zone that does not change with daylight savings. Following example converts UTC to Pacific Standard Time (PST).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

utc = datetime(2019, 8, 7, 10, 30, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
pst = utc.astimezone(timezone(-timedelta(hours=8)))
print(utc)
# 2019-08-07 10:30:00+00:00
print(pst)
# 2019-08-07 02:30:00-08:00
```

To obtain the number of hours of offset for a named time zone:

```
import pytz                                         
def get_standard_time_offset(tz_name):
    t = pytz.timezone(tz_name)
    # DATE HERE IS AN ARBITRARY WINTER DATE THAT WOULDN'T WORK IN THE SOUTHERN HEMISPHERE
    offset = t.utcoffset(datetime(2010,1,1))
    hrsoffset = offset.total_seconds()/3600
    return hrsoffset
```

Comment: This is great thanks!  The last thing I need then is a method to get the timedelta hours for a named timezone.  This function below does that step:                                               
    def get_standard_time_offset(tz_name):
        t = timezone(tz_name)
        offset = t.utcoffset(datetime(2010,1,1))
        hrsoffset = offset.total_seconds()/3600
        return hrsoffset

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_dt = "enter here UTC time "

utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)
```